# Form of ideal generated by a set in non-commutative case

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I am unable to visualize how a the ideal generated by a set looks like in case of non-commutative ring.
**Question:**
Suppose $R$ is a non-commutative ring with 1$\ne$0 and $R[x,y,z,w]$ be the polynomial ring.
 Let $I_{1}$, $I_{2}$ and $I_{3}$ be three ideals of $R[x,y,z,w]$.
Where, $I_{1}=(x,y)$; $I_{2}=(z,w)$; $I_{3}=(xz,xw,yz,yw)$.

I want to know that know how the elements of the ideals $I_{1}$, $I_{2}$ and $I_{3}$ look like in a set form?
 Futher, I also want to if $f\in R[x,y,z,w]$ and $I_{4}=(f)$. Then, how the elements of $I_{4}$ look like in a set form?

Also, please give me hint on how to show that $I_{3}\subset I_{1}\cap I_{2}$ if $R$ is a commutative ring. 
 
Please Help.
**Note:** ideal here means two-sided ideal(bilateral)

Comment: As for the last question, just show that each generator of $I_3$ is contained in both $I_1$ and $I_2$.  Are you assuming that variable *don't* commute with each other in the polynomial ring?

Comment: When you say "ideal" do you mean "bilateral ideal" or "left ideal" or "right ideal  ?

Comment: @RobertShore Yes, we assume that variables also commute. But, Your question has made me to think that if we assume that variables, don't commute. Will there exists polynomial rings of more than one variable containing non-trivial ideals?? As far as I could think, the answer is no. Please give me some proof if the answer is yes, and the type of setting where they exists. Thanks :)

Comment: If variables don't commute with each other, what you have is a free R-module.  Elements are just sums of $R$-multiples of words using the variables (for example, $3xwz^2xy+7yxyz^4$).  If $R$ doesn't commute with the variables either, then elements of $R$ can appear within those words.  But I think it's likely that in your case the variables are meant to commute with each other and with R, so you have a vanilla polynomial ring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for the second Question, Observe that $I_{3}=I_{1}I_{2}$.

Now, We know that for any finite set of the proper ideal $S=\{I_{1}, I_{2},..., I_{n}\}$of $R$, when $R$ is commutative, the following holds true in General:
$$I_{1}I_{2}...I_{n}\subset I_{1}\cap I_{2}\cap...\cap I_{n}$$